# View existing filters in Cognos 7 (Impromptu)

Tags: report, cognos

I'm converting some Cognos 7 Impromptu reports into Cognos 8 by recreating them from scratch.

The one thing I'm not sure about are Filters; when I look at Cognos 8 filters I can clearly see where existing filters are. But looking at the Query -> Filter tab in Cognos 7 I can't tell where I would look for existing filters. I can see how to create them, but not view them:

[image]

Where do I check for existing filters and their definitions in Cognos 7? I don't need to add/alter them, I just need to see which ones exist (and be able to tell when none exist) and see their corresponding definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is the box, any and all filters in Cognos 7 appear to always be in this same text box. Multiple conditions must be chained in the one text field.

[image: Cognos 7 filter]

I as confused because Cognos 8 splits Filters into "things" which can have more than one condition:

[image: Cognos 8 filter]

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check the summary filters in Impromptu - change the filter type drop-down to 'Summary.